# How to use .htaccess rewrite rules to remove .php and folders from URLs?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to simplify the URLs using rewrite  condtions and rules on my local WAMP website.  For example I would like to have `/ProjetSyntheseFAC/mammiferes` instead of `/ProjetSyntheseFAC/pages/animaux/mammiferes.php`.

I have to remove folders from the URL and delete the ".php" from the end.
Everything I've tried either does not work or produces an internal server error.

Here is my folder hierarchy:

```
/wwww/ProjectSyntheseFAC/: 
- index.php
- .htaccess
- pages: 
     - animaux:
           - mammiferes.php
           - oiseaux.php
           - reptiles.php
     - infos:
           - access.php
           - contact.php
           - plan.php
     - spectacle: 
           - reserverPlace.php
           - spectacle.php`
```

Here is what I tried last:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mammiferes$ /pages/animaux/mammiferes.php
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} . [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)
RewriteRule !\.[a-z0-4]{2,4}$ /pages/animaux/%1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule (.*) /pages/animaux/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It looks like your rewrite rules may need to include the project folder in them.   Something like `RewriteRule ^ProjetSyntheseFAC/mammiferes$ /ProjetSyntheseFAC/pages/animaux/mammiferes.php`  or you might be able to use your existing rewrite rules by setting `RewriteBase /ProjetSyntheseFAC/` just after turning on the rewrite engine.

Comment: How does your `/ProjectSyntheseFAC` subdirectory fit into your "folder hierarchy"? Is this the equivalent of your `Project:` folder in your hierarchy? Or, what is the relevance of `Project:` in your hierarchy, as it appears to be at the same level as `pages:`? What is the _document root_?

Comment: _Aside:_ Are you intending to later transfer this to a "live" site? What will happen to the "project" subdirectory then?

Comment: Cross-site post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761442/htaccess-url-rewriting-delete-folders-delete-php